# how to display child of child?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

i have one table called content where in I am adding top level pages and child pages. The top level page will have `parent__id as the id of page title home` and child pages will have their respective `parent__id`. when i add pages it something look like this.

```
id parent__id title and so on.
1     0       Home
2     1       About
3     2       services
4     1       contact us
```

here I want to display it like

```
Home
  >About
   >>services
  >contact
```

i have tried this

```
<cfquery name="d" datasource="mydata">
    SELECT p.id as parentid,
           p.title as parent,
           p.nav_depth,
           c.id as childid,
           c.title as child,
           c.parent__id as child_parentid 
    from content p
    left join content as c on c.parent__id = p.id
    where p.site__id = "8432381492061036983"
    group by p.id, c.id
    order by  p.id, c.id, c.nav_order
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#d#">  

<cfoutput query="d" group="parentid">
    <cfif d.nav_depth EQ 0>
        #d.parent#<br />
        <cfif d.parentid EQ d.child_parentid>
        <cfoutput>> #d.child#<br /></cfoutput> 
        </cfif>
     </cfif>
     <cfif d.nav_depth GT 0>
            <cfif d.childid EQ d.child_parentid>
             <cfoutput> >> #d.child<br /></cfoutput>
          </cfif>
     </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

I got the output like this. when i look into the dump it shows correct result.

```
Home
> About US
> Services
```

can any help me out what should i do in the query or cfoutput to mark the child of child differently and to display it just below the parent? 
here is my complete table structure with data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a29fc/1/0. Thanks

Comment: Please explain the concept of pages as you see it.  There seems to be a disconnect between your prose and your code.

Comment: By default there will be one page called `Home` in content table later on whenever you add pages they will be child of home, for example add page called `about` it will be the child home then you create another page called `services` it will be child of about when you look for path it will be like this. home/about/services

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where child is coming from, but what you need is a nested group output. This should get you on the right track. The biggest thing to watch is that your query is ordered in the order they should display on the screen. Your current SQL Fiddle isn't doing that part correctly.

```
<cfoutput query="d" group="parentid">
  #d.parent#<br />
  <cfoutput group="child"><!--- group based on child --->
    > #d.child#<br /><!--- output child header --->
    <cfoutput>
      >> #d.child<br /><!--- all matching children for current d.child --->
    </cfoutput>
  </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

This would output

```
Home
> About Us
>> Our Works
> Contact Us
```

Comment: I have tried this but its giving something else 
`Home
> About US
>> About US
> Services
>> Services
> our works
>> our works`

Comment: You need to order your query correctly and update the second d.child reference to the correct value

Comment: I am ordering query to parentid it is showing correct i think. referencing to the correct this what i am wondering about :(